# android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ",": syntax error

Tags: android

I'm using room database to store data. Everything is working fine but when I try to update the table I get the
E/UncaughtException: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ",": syntax error

Here's the table

```
@Entity(tableName = "tbl_routine_activity")
data class ActivityModel(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val id:Int,
    val activityName:String?,
    val color:String?,
    val purpose:List<String>?,
    val material:List<String>?,
    val steps:List<String>?,
    val routineName:List<Int>?,
    val isCompleted:Boolean?,
    val isFavorite:Boolean?
)
```

and here's the dao

```
@Query(
        "UPDATE tbl_routine_activity SET activityName =:activityName,color=:color,purpose=:purpose,"+
                " material=:material, steps=:steps, routineName=:routineName," +
                "isCompleted=:isCompleted, isFavorite=:isFavorite WHERE id =:id"
    )
    fun update(
        activityName: String?
         ,color: String?
        , purpose: List<String>?
        , material: List<String>?
        , steps: List<String>?
        , routineName: List<Int>?
        , isCompleted: Boolean?
        , isFavorite: Boolean?
        ,id: Int
    )
```

I get this error when I'm trying to update the table with an empty list or list with more than one value.
When the list has more than one data I get
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "?": syntax error
while compiling: UPDATE tbl_routine_activity SET activityName = ?,color=? ,purpose=?,?, material=?,?, steps=?, routineName=?, isCompleted=?, isFavorite=? WHERE id =?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`List` directly use in Query means `range`.

example:

```
@Query("SELECT * from table where name IN :listOfName)
    fun getItems(listOfName: List<String>): List<Item>
```

In your case, the first `List` was **purpose**, so it will cause syntax problem when parse to SQL.
`purpose = :purpose` will be parsed to `purpose = (purpose1, purpose2, .. )`

I think that's why exception says `purpose=?,?,`

---

### UPDATE

Originally I thought your're missing `TypeConvert`, but I'm wrong, this case is no matter with `TypeConverter`.

I do a test with a snippet code and found that the source implement with `dao` will do this

```
  @Override
  public void test(final int id, final List<String> names) {
    ...
    _stringBuilder.append("UPDATE _test SET names=");
    final int _inputSize = names.size();
    StringUtil.appendPlaceholders(_stringBuilder, _inputSize);
    ...
  }
```

and go in `StringUtil.appendPlaceholders()`

```
   public static void appendPlaceholders(StringBuilder builder, int count) {
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            builder.append("?");
            if (i < count - 1) {
                builder.append(",");
            }
        }
    }
```

It will append counts of "?" with `List` size, and it will also cause the problem said at the beginning.

Base on this, I think you need to parse `List<String>` as a full `String` by yourself before pass it, `TypeConverter` does not do it for you.

Comment: I do have defined typeconverter  
    fun restoreList(list: String): List<String>? {
        return Gson().fromJson(list, object : TypeToken<List<String>?>() {}.type)
    }

  
    fun storeList(list: List<String>?): String {
        return Gson().toJson(list)
    }  and have added this on database class Database(entities = [CreateActivityModel::class], version = 6, exportSchema = true)
TypeConverters(TypeConverter::class)
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun createActivityDao(): CreateActivityDao
}

Comment: I updated my answer and have some test result, please check.

Comment: Can I ask you a few more questions?

Comment: Sure, please. But if your question is not related with original post, I'll recommend you create a new question.

Comment: I'm currently using either AsyncTask.execute{} or doAsync{} to run database operation? Are these the right way to do it?

Comment: Yes, there is no problem with those. In easy word, any operations with database in multi-thread is OK. But real performance depends on the complexity of the cases with using Thread, Executor, AsyncTask etc.

Answer (score 0):

syntax error says `,purpose=?,?, material=?,?,` - you have here some duplicated question marks, investigate once again query. it can't be exacly same as you pasted, because you have `activityName =:activityName` and log says `activityName = ?` - space before question mark, not present in query

try with this (cleaned up):

```
"UPDATE tbl_routine_activity SET activityName=:activityName, color=:color, purpose=:purpose, "+
            "material=:material, steps=:steps, routineName=:routineName, " +
            "isCompleted=:isCompleted, isFavorite=:isFavorite WHERE id=:id"
```

Comment: that purpose=?,?, material=?,?, is when I'm trying  to update the list with two data